# Configure font based on the language

Tags: visual-studio-code

I just installed VS Code and I like it.

I want to know if it's possible to configure the editor to use a specific font for a particular language. For instance, for Python I'd like to use "Liberation Mono", and for Rust I'd like to use "Source Code Pro". This should be configured automatically btw. Actually, a keyboard shortcut to switch fonts is also fine.

Comment: you can set a different font per workspace in the settings.json

Answer (score 6):

Yes this is possible!

You can configure settings for languages in your `settings.json`

> To customize your editor by language, run the global command `Preferences: Configure Language Specific Settings` (command id: `workbench.action.configureLanguageBasedSettings`) from the Command Palette (<kbd>Ctrl+Shift+P</kbd>) which opens the language picker. Selecting the language you want, opens the Settings editor with the language entry where you can add applicable settings.
>   <sub>(https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/settings#_language-specific-editor-settings)</sub>

To change the font you would insert:

```
"editor.fontFamily": "YOUR FONT HERE"
```

Answer (score 0):

To configure editor font by language use the following format

```
"[language]": {
       // here goes your configurations
      }
```

for example:

```
"[javascript]": {
    "editor.fontFamily": "Monaspace Neon, Fira Code, Monaco, monospace"
  }
```

this would configure vscode to use Monaspace neon font if you open a javascript file